# Qt Designer code generation issue

Tags: c++, python, qt, user-interface, qt-designer

I am using Qt Designer. When I lauch the code generation (View code), I have the following issue:

```
Code Generation Failed 
Unable to launch C:/Python27/Lib/site-packages/PyQt4\uic.
```

I tried to use the tips [here](https://code.google.com/p/pythonxy/issues/detail?id=216)

> ```
> You can generate code by using the pyuic4.bat file 
> located under the PyQt4 install directory, on Win usually
> C:/Python##/Lib/site-packages/PyQt4. 
> Usage from the command line is:
> pyuic4.bat inputfile.ui > output.py
> ```

`pyuic4.bat inputfile.ui > output.py` gives me an output.py file, but launching this output.py script gives nothing. The execution is pending for a while, then stop. I don't know if code has been generated / where it should have been generated ... What I would like is the code in C++/Qt.  What should I do once I have output.py ?

Could somebody explain more precisely how to proceed ? Is this tip making possible to see the rendering of the UI, or the generated code (which I want) ? Where can I find the code ? What is another working trick ?

Comment: If you use pyuic4 you get python-code as output and no C++-code, so do you want writing something in python (with PyQt) or in C++ (with Qt)?

Comment: Thanks for reply, I want the code in C++ (with Qt). However, when I do View Code, I get this error with `Unable to launch C:/Python27/Lib/site-packages/PyQt4\uic.` Is it because i am configured to output python code ? How to see the C++ code ?

Comment: That is a bit strange. It seems that you are using the Qt Designer form PyQt. Have you installed Qt and PyQt? If yes there are probably two Qt Designers, one from PyQt and one from (C++) Qt. But with C++ I can't help, because I have only used PyQt and Python and no C++ with Qt.

Comment: I Think you shouldn't use Qt Designer, but Qt Creator for Qt and C++.

Comment: It seems that QT Designer also can output C++ code, but dont know how to do...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this way to generate C++ file

cmd

`uic -o sample.h sample.ui`

with `sample.ui` the .ui file first saved with Qt Designer. Code is generated in `sample.h`